# Can I get 240 volts to a hard-wired baseboard heater by plugging into a nearby outlet?

Tags: electrical

I need some help I have a 42 inch cadet baseboard heater that needs 240 volts to run at full power. The heater is in a small water meter room I have it hard wired in but its only 120volts coming in and I noticed a 15 amp plug close by that is on a different breaker so I was wondering if i can wire a plug to the heater and plug it in while its still hard wired in to get the additional 120 volts so the heater runs at full power or can I just remove plug and hard wire it from there to thanks

Comment: That's one long sentence you have there. Would be much easier to read if you punctuated it a bit.

Answer (score 3):

You can run a 240V heater on 120V if you really want to, but it'll be weak tea, operating at 1/4 of power.

You could attempt what you hope, but it will require completely redoing the circuit wiring, to have 2 hots and a neutral in the same cable, at least up to the point where a 120V-only subcircuit branches off. **All the conductors must be in the same cable**. You cannot grab one hot from this cable and another hot from another cable.

Also, the fixed loads on each half of the circuit must account for less than 50% of circuit capacity.  Otherwise you can't have any receptacles on it at all.  This is per pole, so if you have a 6 amp heater on both poles obviously, and a 5A sump pump on one pole, that pole can't have any receptacles.

You must use a 2-**pole** breaker with 240V between the poles, otherwise you create a serious overload hazard (and also the heater won't work). An example of a bad breaker to use is a double-stuff that fits in one space.

Doing this type of wiring correctly is hard, and easy to get wrong.  It's harder than using punctuation, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically if the two breakers are on different legs, this would work, but it is a REALLY bad idea. This is likely a code violation and it's just not safe to do. You have 2 breakers that operate independently which is not good. Plus you could run into back feed issues.

Comment: What if I put a double pull breaker in the breaker box because the breakers are right next to each other

Comment: This is such a bad idea that you shouldn't even suggest it.  This is just crazy unsafe.